# SELECT queries performance impact when the Clickhouse table is continuously populated with INSERT INTO

Tags: buffer, clickhouse

The Clickhouse table, MergeTree Engine, is continuously populated with “INSERT INTO … FORMAT CSV” queries, starting empty. The average input rate is 7000 rows per sec. The insertion is happening in batches of few thousand rows. This has severe performance impact when SELECT queries are executed concurrently. As described in the Clickhouse documentation, the system needs at most 10 minutes to merge the data of a specific table (re-index). But this is not happening as the table is continuously populated.

This is also evident in the file system. The table folder has thousands of sub-folders and the index is over-segmented. If the data ingestion stops, after a few minutes the table is fully merged, and the number of sub-folders becomes a dozen.

In order to encounter the above weakness, the Buffer Engine was used to buffer the table data ingestion for 10 minutes. Consequently, the buffer maximum number of rows is on average 4200000.

The initial table is remaining at most 10 minutes behind as the buffer is keeping the most recently ingested rows. The table is finally merged, and the behaviour is the same as in case where the table has stopped to be populated for a few minutes.
But the Buffer table, which corresponds to the combination of the buffer and the initial table, is getting severely slower.

From the above appears that, if the table is continuously populated, it is not merging, and indexing suffers. Is there a way to avoid this weakness?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible create statements of tables, which you use?

Answer (score 3):

The number of sub-folders in the table data directory is not so representative value.

Indeed, each sub-folder contains a data part consisting of sorted (indexed) rows. If several data parts are merged into a new bigger one the new sub-folder appears.

However, source data parts are not removed instantly after the merge. There is a `<merge_tree>` setting `old_parts_lifetime` defining a delay after which the parts will be removed, by default it set to 8 minutes. Also, there is `cleanup_delay_period` setting defining how often a background cleaner checks and removes outdated parts, it is 30 seconds by default.

So, it is normal to have such amount of sub-folders for about 8 minutes and 30 seconds after the ingestion starts. If it is unacceptable to you, you can change these settings.

It makes sense to check the amount of **active** parts in a table only (i.e. parts which have not been merged into a bigger one). To do so, you could run the following query: `SELECT count() FROM system.parts WHERE database='db' AND table='table' AND active`.

Moreover, ClickHouse does such checks internally if the amount of active parts in a partition is greater than `parts_to_delay_insert=150`, it will slow down INSERTs, but if it is greater than `parts_to_throw_insert=300` it will abort insertions.